# Conexão Cassandra + Spark + R

Tags: r, cassandra, spark

Como faço para conectar o Cassandra com o spark?

Cassandra > Spark > R

Já consegui conectar o R ao Spark, agora preciso levar os dados que estão armazenados no Cassandra para o Spark e finalmente analisar no R. Alguém poderia me ajudar?
Desde já obrigada.

Answer (score 0):

O Spark não sabe como falar de Cassandra, mas sua funcionalidade pode ser estendida através do uso de conectores. O pessoal da DataStax produziu um conector usando Spark e Scala  (linguagem de script que é executada na JVM) e esta disponível para download no GitHub:

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector

Após construir o repositório no seu computador, haverá dois arquivos jar em um diretório chamado "target", um para o Scala e outro para o Java. É bom ter os jar acessível através de um caminho que seja fácil de lembrar.

Inicie o Spark novamente (a partir do diretório spark), mas desta vez carregue o jar (lembre-se de setar o diretório onde o jar esta):

```
bin/spark-shell --jars ~/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly-1.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Agora digite o seguinte no prompt do scala:

```
sc.stop
import com.datastax.spark.connector._, org.apache.spark.SparkContext, org.apache.spark.SparkContext._, org.apache.spark.SparkConf
val conf = new SparkConf(true).set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

Isso pega o contexto do Spark e o substitui por um que esteja conectado à sua cassandra local.

Digite o seguinte no shell do scala:

```
val test_spark_rdd = sc.cassandraTable("NOME_KEYSPACE", "SUA_TABELA")
test_spark_rdd.first
```

(em vez de `NOME_KEYSPACE` e `SUA_TABELA`, coloque Keyspace e a tabela do cassandra).

Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma.
Att